# Function with any number of int params typing hint

Tags: python, function, python-typing

```py
def f() -> Callable[[ # how to show there can be any number of int?
                    ], float]:
    def g(*args):
        assert all(type(x) == int for x in args)
        return 0.1
    return g
```

I read the typing docs and [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) (i.e. `Callable[…, ReturnType]`) is not what I need.

I know `Tuple[int, …]`, but `Callable[[int, …], float]` return Error `"…" not allowed in this context Pylance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining a `Protocol` with a `__call__` whose function signature has the desired typing:

```
from typing import Protocol


class IntCallable(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, *args: int) -> float: ...


def f() -> IntCallable:
    def g(*args: int) -> float:
        assert all(type(x) == int for x in args)
        return 0.1
    return g
```

Testing it out with mypy:

```
f()(1, 2, 3)  # fine
f()("foo")    # error: Argument 1 to "__call__" of "IntCallable" has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"
```

The other option is to have your function take a single `Iterable[int]` argument instead of an arbitrary number of `int` arguments, which lets you use a simple `Callable` typing instead of having to go the more complex `Protocol` route.